# Post auto generated image to Facebook from Google App Engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I've hosted one of my Facebook app on Google App Engine (PHP). This app generates a dynamic image using GD library. The image generation script is in **result_image.php**. It generates and displays the resultant image without any problem. Now I want to publish this image on Facebook. How can I accomplish this? The constraints I'm facing are:

- GAE doesn't support CURL or HttpRequest though they support Fetching URL but I'm not sure how can I post that result_image.php content.
- GAE doesn't support saving or creating new file

Here is my *php.ini* at root of my project to enable uploading.

```
    file_uploads=1
    max_file_uploads=1
    upload_max_filesize=5M
```

I tried this. But obviously didn't work.

```
    $args = array(
                'message'   => 'My Message,
                'source'      => "@".realpath('result_image.php')             
            );
    $post_id = $facebook->api("/me/photos", "post", $args);
```

Comment: you can create and save files with GAE but you just can't save them locally (to your app). you can save them to the datastore/blobstore/bucket etc.

Comment: @PaulCollingwood I'm not using datastore since it requires billing enabled. :(

Comment: The best option is saving the image to GCS (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/), then use CloudStorageTools::getPublicUrl() to generate a publicly accessible URL: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/#generating_a_public_url_for_google_cloud_storage_objects